# How to retrieve certain number of images from a wordpress post?

Tags: posts, wp-query, images, query

I need to retrieve only the first 5 images for a wordpress post but I don't know how to do this. I need to use this on a custom blog to be used on my home page. Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to get a post's attachments:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
    ) );
```

Comment: Glad to be of service!